# Reference Request: (Borel) Iwahori Spherical Representations

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups

I was told that Borel had a result about Iwahori Spherical automorphic representations being upper-triangular (/semistable). Where can I find this?

Comment: Could you make your question more precise (what is the exact mathematical context ?). Borel studied the *local components* of automorphic representations that are Iwahori spherical : Admissible representations of a semi-simple group over a local field with vectors fixed under an Iwahori subgroup.
Invent. Math. 35 (1976), 233--259. But maybe you was thinking of something else ?

Comment: Paul, this is the reference i was requesting. Thanks a bunch!